# How can I enter and display non-ascii characters when using `docker exec <container name> bash`

Tags: bash, docker, unicode

When connecting to a docker instance on the command line using `docker exec <container name> bash` whenever I enter non-ascii characters such as `ø`, `å` or `æ` my command line freaks out and displays `(arg: 8)`.

Docker will insist on escaping file names containing these characters when using `ls`.

Docker *will* however display the *contents* of files containing these characters without escaping.

How do I make docker consistently accept these characters on the command line without escaping?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/675142/why-is-the-special-character-escaped-in-the-command-line

Comment: @Pino Yes I expect that this is a problem with locales. Another way of posing the question would be: how can locale be set correctly in Docker?

Comment: What character encoding do you want to use? The characters you provide as example are present in several encoding schemes.

Comment: You may need to adjust the settings of your terminal emulator or check the encoding settings of your host machine to ensure it supports UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to set the locale inside the Docker container to support UTF-8 characters like this

```
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
```

and then rebuild the Docker image using the updated Dockerfile!

```
docker build -t <YOUR_IMAGE> .
```

now run new container using the updated image like below

```
docker run -it <YOUR_IMAGE> bash
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set

```
  environment:
    - LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
```

in `docker-compose.yml`